# Unusual working of UBUNTU 18.04 LTS in my laptop

Tags: drivers, graphics

I'm new to ubuntu & running ubuntu 18.04 in my HP Laptop,

---Specs---

Processor -  i5 - 8th gen

RAM       -  8 GB

Graphics  -  RTX 2060

---

I have enough processing power, but the OS isn't functioning as usual from the installation.

The problems i face are,

-> Frequent hanging.

-> Display lags 
   ( I even tried to reinstall the graphic drivers, but didn't get solved. After installation in the setting->details panel, my graphics card details are not displayed )

Please let me know the status,
& thanks in advance for your valuable answers.

Comment: Make sure to fully update the system then install the latest Nvidia driver version. Use Additional drivers for that.

Comment: How much swap do you use? The terminal command `free` will show you.